# ExtJs remoteCombo on editorgrid

Tags: extjs

okay, this time it is a remote combo.

I have both cityID (Guid) & CityName(text) fields in the grids store.

Grid column is set on the CityId field with a ComboBox editor with a remote store, CityName field is not used.

So how can I deal with Id/Value issue.

So far, I added a renderer function for the CityId column, which just returns CityName, but if you try to edit the cell and ComboBox activates, you just see the Guid of the city. I am sure this is asked many times but I cannot find a clear and documented solution.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Code would definitely help... but make sure you are using the displayField and valueField settings on your combobox to associate the correct fields in the store.